# How to avoid big delays on concurrent database queries?

Tags: java, oracle, apache, jdbc, cgi

I am writing a small program, which is going to be launched on Apache web-server (not Tomcat) through CGI in respond to a POST request.

The program does the following:

1. read the xml, sent via http in request
2. execute a stored procedure in a database with the data extracted from the xml
3. return the result of the stored procedure as the respond to the POST request

The database is Oracle. I use jdbc OCI to access it.

```
Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

String dbCS = "jdbc:oracle:oci:@//ip:port/service"

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbCS, dbUserId, dbPwd);
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{ call ? := my_pkg.my_sp(?,?,?,?)}");
cs.registerOutParameter(pReturnValue, OracleTypes.NUMBER);
cs.setInt("p1", p1);
cs.setString("p2", p2);
cs.setString("p3", p3);
cs.registerOutParameter("p_out", Types.VARCHAR);
try {
    cs.executeQuery();
    return cs.getString(pReqResponse);
} finally {
    try {
        cs.close();
   } catch (SQLException ex) {
        //....        
   }
}
```

While doing a single request, it worked fine (the whole programm finished in 2 sec.). However, if I tryed to send multiple POST requests at once, I got **all of them** stuck for some amount of time, depending on the quantity of requests (it's approximately, 10 sec. for 10 req., 15 sec. for 15 req.).

I tried to estimate, which part of code gave the delay. It appeared to be two lines:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbConnectionString, dbUserId, dbPwd);
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("{ call ? := my_pkg.my_sp(?,?,?,?)}");
```

The execution itself finished almost immediatelly.

Why is this so?

P.S.: I experimented the same on Windows7. Of course, it wasn't launched from a web server, but just as a simple console process. It also has to read the xml from a file on a hard drive. All concurrently launched instances of the programm finished in a second all together.

What prevents it from working as fast on Linux through Apache?

---

Based on comments

I tried to set poolling properties for my connection but all in vain. I tried the following:

1. While specifying UserId and Password in the url

   ```
   jdbc:oracle:oci:login/password@//ip:port/service
   ```

   I tried to set the connection properties:

   ```
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty("Pooling", "true");
    p.setProperty("Min Pool Size", "1");
    p.setProperty("Max Pool Size", "10");
    p.setProperty("Incr Pool Size", "4");

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbConnectionString, p);
   ```
2. I tried to use [OCI Connection Pooling](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/ociconpl.htm):

   ```
    OracleOCIConnectionPool cpool = new OracleOCIConnectionPool();
    cpool.setUser("user");
    cpool.setPassword("pwd");
    cpool.setURL(dbConnectionString);

    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.put(OracleOCIConnectionPool.CONNPOOL_MIN_LIMIT, "1");
    p.put(OracleOCIConnectionPool.CONNPOOL_MAX_LIMIT, "5");
    p.put(OracleOCIConnectionPool.CONNPOOL_INCREMENT, "2");
    p.put(OracleOCIConnectionPool.CONNPOOL_TIMEOUT, "10");
    p.put(OracleOCIConnectionPool.CONNPOOL_NOWAIT, "true");
    cpool.setPoolConfig(p);

    Connection conn = (OracleOCIConnection) cpool.getConnection();
   ```
3. I tried to use the [apache DBCP component](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/):

   ```
   basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
   basicDataSource.setUsername("user");
   basicDataSource.setPassword("pwd");
   basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");
   basicDataSource.setUrl(dbConnectionString);

   Connection conn = basicDataSource.getConnection();
   ```

The behaviour remained the same, i.e. a big delay on `getConnection` in all concurrent requests.

All these attempts seem to try to solve some other problem to me, as in my case all connections are established from separate processes, and it looks unobvious to manage connections from one pool among different processes (am I mistaken here??).

What options do I have? Or probably did I do anything wrong?
Also I should say, I am quite new to java in general, so I may be missing some basic things..

---

Could this be an OS or web-server issue? Probably something should be setup there, not in code...?

---

Also I tried to use `thin` client instead of `oci`. However it worked even more weirdly: the first request finished in a second, while the second delayed for a **minute**.

---

[Poor concurrency with Oracle JDBC drivers](https://forums.oracle.com/thread/501397) states a problem similar to mine.

---

In the end we found out that processes, launched by Apache through CGI, occupied all 100% of CPU (and a lion share of memory), so they simply did not have enough resources. Unfortunately I do not know, why a very simple and basic programm (reading an xml and establishing one connection to DB to execute a stored procedure) launched simultanuosly only 20 times, eats all resources.

However the solution appeared to be very obvious indeed. I've refactored it to a java web application using servlets, we deployed it on Apache Tomcat, and MAGIC....it started working as expected, without any visible effect on resources.

Comment: Maybe something to do with your database connections settings.

Comment: @JunedAhsan I would greatly appreciate, if you could suggest the "something".

Comment: how about your connection pool size? maxConnection settings?

Comment: @JunedAhsan I've just tried to. This didn't change anything. Could you examine my question's update to review, if I missed something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with cgi. When you make a cgi request, it starts a new cpu process to handle the request. Each new request is also in a new JVM, so connection pooling is not an option.

Even so, it should be quicker than that to get a connection. Maybe in Oracle itself there are config options governing the number of concurrent connections you can have, but I'm no Oracle expert.